# Добавить картинку в <input type=range .... >

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

Собственно, в чём вопрос. Делаю Range Slider. Хочу вот добавить вместо обычного range (она же кнопка прокрутки) изображение. Как это сделать?)

```
введите сюда код
```

[Ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/pornhubchristmasclub/3zpk04o9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как реализовано на CSS изменение вида RANGE:

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: none !important;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0; }
  input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; }
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: #0275d8;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -0.35rem; }
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: #0275d8;
    cursor: pointer; }
  input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent; }
  input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    border-radius: 10px; }
  input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 10px; }
  input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: #0275d8;
    cursor: pointer; }
  input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #eee; }

datalist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -6px; }
  datalist option::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    text-indent: 0; }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="size" name="size" class="form-control form-control-sm" min="1" max="5" step="1" list="range_list">
<datalist id="range_list">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</datalist>
```